# AppleScript fill out textfield

Tags: popup, click, applescript

I try to fill up a textfield but can't

```
activate application "****"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "****"
        tell text field 1 of window 1
            set value of text field 1 to "here is the text"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: I actually fix it with delay 3
  click text field 1 of window 1
  delay 3
  keystroke "***" but its not always working

Comment: The second `of text field 1` is too much. It's just `set value to "here is the text"`

Comment: The script actually passing with this, but nothing its filled on the actual text fieldactivate application "****"
tell application "System Events"
 tell process "***"
  delay 1
  select text field 1 of window 1
  set value to "****"
  delay 2
 end tell
end tell

Answer (score 5):

```
activate application "****"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "****"
        set value of text field 1 of window 1 to "here is the text"
    end tell
end tell
```

This works for me if you want to try.

Comment: `text field 1` does it target the first text field in the application? if so, I tried it but it does not work for me.